# Deserialize an object that can have string or int from JSON format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

How do I deserialize an object from JSON format with valid data using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(useCaseData)`?

I tried it with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(useCaseData)`

But I get this error :
`` Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value 1 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'. Path '', line 1, position 1. ``

Base class:

```
public class ReadUseCaseLogDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UseCaseName { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExecutedAt { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

    }
```

Data that returns string values:

```
{
    "totalCount": 281,
    "currentPage": 14,
    "itemsPerPage": 10,
    "pageCount": 29,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 131,
            "useCaseName": "Read use case logs using Entity Framework",
            "data": {
                "DateFrom": [],
                "DateTo": [],
                "UseCaseName": [],
                "Fullname": []
            },
```

This convert throws an error because it cannot convert from int to string:

```
        {
            "id": 9,
            "useCaseName": "Delete brand using Entity Framework",
            "data": 1,
            "executedAt": "2023-06-06T00:08:56.8566667",
            "userId": 4
        }
```

Can some generic be used or something else?

Comment: "deserializing an object **to** JSON format" is a weird thing to say.  Did you mean "deserialize an object **from** JSON format"?

Comment: Also, why do you have data that is sometimes an integer then other times something else?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. It should say deserialize an object from json

Comment: I have use case logger that logs what data user provided

Comment: Could use either `dynamic` or `JToken` I suppose. But probably best to fix your input so it's more normalized

Answer (score 0):

If you use an object rather than a string it should work:

> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Object>>(useCaseData)

Answer (score 0):

you have an Array, not a Dictionary, so try this code

```
List<ReadUseCaseLogDto> items = JObject.Parse(useCaseData)["items"]
                                       .ToObject<List<ReadUseCaseLogDto>>();
```